# Websitepanel restore failure

Tags: .net, sql-server

Help me.  I am stuck 32 hours into a server migration that was supposed to last about 6 hours.  I for the life of me can't restore this server.  I backed up Website panel from my old server, copied that file over to my new server, changed the Backup catalog setting (had to) and I stil cant get this to work.  I tried disabling the FK constraints in SQL and the system restored my files and sites in IIS (also created the local users) but it did not populate any data into websitepanel.  I am not sure what I am doing wrong.  Please help!

> 00:03:51
>   Restore HomeFolder 'C:\HostingSpaces\somesite'
>   00:04:50
>
> Can't restore item The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN
>   KEY constraint "FK_ServiceItems_Packages". The conflict occurred in
>   database "WebsitePanel", table "dbo.Packages", column 'PackageID'. The
>   statement has been terminated.  at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception,
>   Boolean breakConnection)  at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning()  at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior,
>   SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream,
>   BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj)  at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds,
>   RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)  at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior
>   cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean
>   async)  at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String
>   method, DbAsyncResult result)  at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(DbAsyncResult
>   result, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe)  at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()  at
>   Microsoft.ApplicationBlocks.Data.SqlHelper.ExecuteNonQuery(SqlConnection
>   connection, CommandType commandType, String commandText,
>   SqlParameter[] commandParameters) in SQLHelper.cs:line 365  at
>   Microsoft.ApplicationBlocks.Data.SqlHelper.ExecuteNonQuery(String
>   connectionString, CommandType commandType, String commandText,
>   SqlParameter[] commandParameters) in SQLHelper.cs:line 282  at
>   WebsitePanel.EnterpriseServer.DataProvider.AddServiceItem(Int32
>   actorId, Int32 serviceId, Int32 packageId, String itemName, String
>   itemTypeName, String xmlProperties) in DataProvider.cs:line 1103  at
>   WebsitePanel.EnterpriseServer.PackageController.AddPackageItem(ServiceProviderItem
>   item) in PackageController.cs:line 1275  at
>   WebsitePanel.EnterpriseServer.OperatingSystemController.RestoreItem(String
>   tempFolder, XmlNode itemNode, Int32 itemId, Type itemType, String
>   itemName, Int32 packageId, Int32 serviceId, ResourceGroupInfo group)
>   in OperatingSystemController.cs:line 653  at
>   WebsitePanel.EnterpriseServer.BackupController.RestoreInternal(String
>   taskId, Int32 userId, Int32 packageId, Int32 serviceId, Int32
>   serverId, Int32 storePackageId, String storePackageBackupPath, String
>   storeServerBackupPath) in BackupController.cs:line 655

Comment: Looks like I'm calling microsoft support on this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I contacted Microsoft as this was a critical issue in a production server.  Turns out it is a bug and it is being fixed now.  There will be a patch out soon that addresses this issue.

Comment: Turns out it wasn't so much a bug but something they forgot to remove.  There will no longer be a full restore option.